# How to create a manual diff between two Json objects which can be sent to Reviewboard using python?

Tags: python, review-board

How do I create a diff of two json objects such that they are in the manual diff format which can be sent to reviewboard? I need to generate the diff from inside a python script.I think manual diffs are generated using the "diff file1 file2" command line utility. Can I generate a similar reviewboard compatible diff using difflib? Or is there another library that I need to use? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what format reviewboard takes, but if diff'ing JSON, make sure to emit the keys in a particular well-defined order for best results (this will vary based on JSON generator, as dictionaries are technically orderless).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Are there any built in diff libraries in python that you'd suggest? Would something like difflib.context_diff work?

Comment: Just to add reviewboard uses Myers Diff, I think they should be able to handle display my side by side json diff once I send them a prudely generated manual diff. However, I cant figure out the format I need to send them this diff in:((python equivalent of commandline diff i guess) The keys tip is useful though and since its json and not textual diff I'll keep in mind that my json diff is generated as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use difflib:

```
def show_diff(seqm):
    output= []
    for opcode, a0, a1, b0, b1 in seqm.get_opcodes():
        if opcode == 'equal':
            output.append(seqm.a[a0:a1])
        elif opcode == 'insert':
            output.append("<ins>" + seqm.b[b0:b1] + "</ins>")
        elif opcode == 'delete':
            output.append("<del>" + seqm.a[a0:a1] + "</del>")
        elif opcode == 'replace':
            output.append("<del>" + seqm.a[a0:a1] + "</del>" + "<ins>" + seqm.b[b0:b1] + "</ins>" )
        else:
            raise RuntimeError, "Unexpected opcode"
    return ''.join(output)
```

In your situation, you compare your json files (I just used dummy text):

```
In [4]: sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'hello', 'hello world')

In [6]: diff = show_diff(sm)

In [7]: diff
Out[7]: 'hello<ins> world</ins>'
```

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) if you need a different output from difflib

Answer (score 1):

I just think before going through diff, you should reformat JSON object lets say on alphabetical and numeric order.